# Erreur in TimeTrigger Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I currently unable to run TimeTrigger functions in my macOs with the Function CLI version **2.3.148** and **2.3.199**:

[image]

This is my csproj :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim" Version="2.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And all timetrigger are not working (old ones and fresh ones).

Any idea ?

Comment: Since you're running locally, are you using Azure Storage Emulator? If so: is it running when you try to run the functions locally?

Comment: humm... I think you pointed something. I'm running on macOS and from what I know emulator is not available ?

Comment: Have a look at [azurite](https://github.com/azure/azurite)!

Comment: have a look at my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're running locally, you probably need an Azure Storage Emulator. And since you're running on MacOS, the default Azure Storage Emulator won't do the trick.

Have a look at [Azurite](https://github.com/azure/azurite).

> A lightweight server clone of Azure Blob, Queue, and Table Storage that simulates most of the commands supported by it with minimal dependencies.
>
> In order to run Azurite you need Node.js >= 6.0 installed on your system. Azurite works cross-platform on Windows, Linux, and OS X.
>
> After installation you can install Azurite simply with npm which is Node.js package management tool and which is included with every Node.js installation.
>
> `$ npm install -g azurite`